# custom cell hide other custom cell when scroll to top

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem when I scroll to top my tableview. I have an image view in the second cell that hide other buttons in the first.
[image]
To solve that I tried to use bringtoFront method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            MPInformationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MPInformationCellIdentifier];
            if (!cell) {
                [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:MPInformationCellIdentifier
                                                      bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass: MPHikePresentationViewController.self]]
                                      forCellReuseIdentifier:MPInformationCellIdentifier];
                
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: MPInformationCellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.delegate = self;
            // Custom cell there with data
            [tableView bringSubviewToFront:cell];
            return cell;
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == weatherDetailsIndex){
            MPWeatherCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MPWeatherCellIdentifier];
            if (!cell) {
                [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:MPWeatherCellIdentifier
                                                      bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass: MPHikePresentationViewController.self]]
                                      forCellReuseIdentifier:MPWeatherCellIdentifier];
                
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MPWeatherCellIdentifier];
                
            }
            
            if(weatherDetails != nil){
                [cell setupCellWithWeatherDTO:weatherDetails];
                
            }
            return cell;
        }
}
```

when I scroll from top to down after launching the view there is no problem and I get the desired result something like that
[image]

Any help please

Comment: you need to link more code

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make sure that the top cell view is actually either a table header view or a section header view. Depends on the specific behavior you want. It should not be a regular tableview cell.